# Error missing potitional argument. Python, Flask, Graphql

Tags: python, flask, graphql

having problems adding an additional field "datetime" when users get created. Despite setting required=False in the CreateUser mutation class, been attempting to fix this on my own for roughly an hour without success. The feeling of giving up is starting to appear so therefore i'm here to ask for help.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_graphql import GraphQLView
import graphene
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType, SQLAlchemyConnectionField
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User("{self.username}" "{self.email}") "{self.password}")'


# Schema Objects
class UserObject(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)


class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        username = graphene.String(required=True)
        email = graphene.String(required=True)
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        joined = graphene.DateTime(required=False)

    user = graphene.Field(lambda: UserObject)

    def mutate(self, info, username, email, password, joined):
        password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        user = User(username=username, email=email, password=password, joined=joined)

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return CreateUser(user=user)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_users = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(UserObject)


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)

app.add_url_rule(
    '/graphql',
    view_func=GraphQLView.as_view(
        'graphql',
        schema=schema,
        graphiql=True
    )
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Error:

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "(sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named joined\n[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, email, password, joined) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]\n[parameters: ('Johannes', 'jns@dmo.no', b'$2b$12$H/E3gfKnuidoC70zgLBoUeQRtm4zRApZ7N/xplAtxFXk.fglpqJQi', '2019-10-18 17:53:11')]\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createUser"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createUser": null
  }
}
```

Comment: You've defined `mutate` as requiring joined-- perhaps try giving it a default?  `def mutate(self, info, username, email, password, joined=None)` so it becomes optional and not required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Doobeh. Sadly this did not do it, i did have hope though.

Comment: It looks like it solved the initial problem-- now it seems it's reporting that the column isn't in the table-- have you verified that the sqlite database is created/has all the columns you're expecting?

Comment: That might be it. On a date right now so cant test it. I could attempt to delete the db and create it again with all tables correctly. @Doobeh

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to back and forth with @Doobeh i managed to solve the problem. The problem was i added "joined" after i had called db.create_all(), so therefore joined did not become a column in my db.

So the solution was to re-run db.create_all() after a deletion of my test database.